# Rossby waves in the atmosphere

Tags: meteorology, climate, fluid-dynamics, coriolis, vorticity

I have trouble understanding the Rossby waves in the atmosphere.
Sometimes they are said to be caused by the jets moving from west to east. But the phase velocity of the waves is in the west direction and the group velocity depends on the number of waves. So how do the waves move now?

Also, it is not clear to me if the Rossby waves are deflected by high/low pressure systems, or do they generate them? And if they generate them, how do they do that? They only move air vertically, so how can high and low pressure areas be created? Does this have anything to do with barotropic and baroclinic conditions?

Comment: way too many questions in this. Focus on one question

Comment: Take a look at this first https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19740/how-can-oceanic-rossby-waves-move-from-east-to-west